# How to get a notification for every new rss message?

Tags: android

In my app there is a button that onClick  load Rss news. i would like to have a notification in my device every time that a new rss message is available,and i would like the user to have the option to use this feature or not..is that possible?thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. You've got a long way to go, I think. Look for tutorials in Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to write that yourself. There are no APIs in the Android SDK for automatically notifying you of changes in RSS feeds.

Comment: is there any other sdk for that job?

Comment: @kostas: There are many RSS feed parsing libraries for Java, some of which work on Android (e.g., android-rss).